# Gnuplot: How to set new line in xtics timefmt

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting a gnuplot diagram with float values in the y-axis and time values in the x-axis.
The plotting itself works like a charm, but I can't get newlines in the time format to work.

If I use the format specifier `"%d.%m.%y %H:%M"` it works like a charm, and the result is: `25.05.1983 17:23`. But when I add a newline character, so I have `"%d.%m.%y\n%H:%M"` the resulting labels are actually containing a line break but all I see is: `25.05.1983`.

I also tried to increase the `bmargin` by several values, up to the point where the resulting plot was squished, but I just can't get the time to be shown.

Is the newline character not supported in a time format? Or does this not work at all with labels? Or maybe the `png enhanced` terminal doesn't support it?

**UPDATE**

Sample input data

```
20140617000045
20140617000245
20140617000445
20140617000645
```

I don't have any space between date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your test data the following script works fine with 4.6.5:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'timetest.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
set format x "%d.%m.%y\n%H:%M"
plot 'test.dat' using 1:0 with lp notitle
```

The output is:

[image]

Yes, the `png` terminal works fine as well (but its output is in general uglier).

Comment: Thank you! I've had an issue with the quotes. Somehow the pattern was set under single quotes and not double quotes!

Comment: Fine :) That shows, why a runnable example script can help ;)