# How can I conditionally replace time with date, in X axis ticks?

Tags: gnuplot

I have various datasets, each potentially spanning multiple days. The datasets have unknown contents at time of writing (as they come from logfiles), and the range of data to display is down to my users at any given time.

I would like an X axis similar to that shown below. Time ticks are displayed as `HH:MM`, but change to the date to mark the start of a new day.

[image]
                                   <sup>(© Advanced Software Engineering Limited — taken from ChartDirector documentation)</sup>

I don't want to show `DD MM HH:MM` on every tick, because [that's a waste of space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763929/560648)!

I've played around with setting `HH:MM` for the auto ticks, then manually adding extra `DD MM` ticks at each midnight (with a leading `\n` in the label). I also tried to make use of the minor ticks:

```
set format x "%d %b"
set xtics <start>,2592000,<end>

set format x "%H:%M"
set mxtics default
```

… but this left me with no ticks at all. Besides, ideally I'd like to just "ask" GnuPlot to do this for me, rather than hardcoding ticks, so that auto-scaling can show/hide ticks depending on how much space is available. (However, as I am generating the GnuPlot script from a C++ program that knows the start/end dates of the data being plotted, I do have the ability to generate `set xtics` commands with specific dates/times in them, if necessary.)

ChartDirector achieves this by allowing us to set "multi-labels", basically ticks whose label format depends on a condition, like "is this the first label of a new day?".

Is there anything similar in GnuPlot? Solution should be compatible with GnuPlot 4.4.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883697/2604213.  That requires 4.6 for `stats`, but you can also pass the data range from your program to the script. Regarding the `set for` syntax I don't know if this is supported in 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of Christoph the following script should set the day instead of the time at midnight tics.

```
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"

day0 = 1467324000     # 2016-07-01 00:00:00 UTC, first day to be shown.
day0 = day0 + 60*60*2 # 2 hours difference for UTC -> CEST conversion (in my case).
num_days = 2          # Time span to be shown.

pbm_offset_rel = 5e-4      # This is for faking the bold font.
pbm_offset = num_days*24*60*60*pbm_offset_rel

# The default grid every 6 hours, minor tics for the hourly grid.
set xtics 21600 format '%H:%M'
set mxtics 6

# Replace tic labels at midnight.
set for [i=0:num_days] xtics add (strftime('%b %d', day0+i*24*60*60) day0+i*24*60*60)

# We move the midnight labels and corresponding grid lines left and right to make them appear bold.
set xtics add (strftime('%b %d', day0) day0 + pbm_offset)
set for [i=1:num_days] xtics add (strftime('%b %d', day0+(i-1)*24*60*60) day0+(i-1)*24*60*60-pbm_offset)
set xtics add (strftime('%b %d', day0+num_days*24*60*60) day0+num_days*24*60*60-2*pbm_offset)

# Use solid/dotted grid lines for major/minor tics.
set grid xtics, mxtics  ls 1 lc 0, ls 0

set xrange  [day0:day0+num_days*24*60*60]

set terminal png size 1280,480
set output "output.png"
set samples 1200
plot sin(0.00005*x)
```

The code is tested with Gnuplot 4.6 on Debian Linux. According to [Gnuplot 4.4](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf) the `set for` syntax should also work with Gnuplot 4.4.

[image: Output from the script above]

Comment: This is so close (and thanks!), but I feel it's not flexible enough. You've hardcoded that there will be a major tick every 6 hours, and that there will be a minor tick every hour. That's fine for your specific dataset, with the example of 2 days, but what if my user plots 6 months' data? Or if my user requests a smaller image size than 1280x480? The axis will be too crowded, and we've lost Gnuplot's auto-scaling magic. Also if the data range doesn't start at midnight, odd things happen.

Comment: Though maybe this is the best Gnuplot can give me, and I'll have to work around these issues separately? I'll play around with this and see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 0):

At the time OP's question gnuplot 5.0 was already out. Anyway, it is somehow possible with gnuplot 4.6 and maybe with some cumbersome workaround even with gnuplot 4.4 (no `sum` or `stats`) at that time.

The following solution tries to avoid the disadvantage of @maij's solution with a hardcoded range and tic distances.
However, you need to plot twice, the first time just to get gnuplot's autoscaled range via the variables `GPVAL_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_X_MAX` which you only get *after* plotting. Depending on the width of the output graph you can set the variable `maxLabelCount`. There is certainly room for improvements.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### replace midnight xtic time by date 
reset session

FILE = "SO39997342.dat"
SecPerHour = 3600
SecPerDay  = 24*SecPerHour
myTimeFmtIn = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"
    
# create some random test data
set table FILE
    set samples 60
    t0 = time(0)
    plot '+' u (strftime(myTimeFmtIn, t0+$0*SecPerHour)):(sin($0/10.)+rand(0)*0.4-0.2) w table
unset table
              
myTimeFmtOut = "%H:%M"
set format x myTimeFmtOut timedate
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmtIn)):2 w l

isMidnight(t)      = int(t)/SecPerDay == t/SecPerDay
myXtic(t)          = isMidnight(t) ? strftime("{/:Bold %b %d}",t) : strftime(myTimeFmtOut,t)
n2t(i)             = d0*SecPerDay + i*SecPerDay*d2
maxLabelCount      = 8
numberOfDays       = (d0=ceil(GPVAL_X_MIN/SecPerDay),d1=floor(GPVAL_X_MAX/SecPerDay),d1-d0)
getNLabels(c,cmax) = (c0=0, c<=cmax ? (c0=c,d2=1) : (sum [j=2:cmax] (c/j<=cmax && !c0 ? (c0=c/j,d2=j) : 0)), c0)
NLabels            = getNLabels(numberOfDays,maxLabelCount)

set for [i=0:NLabels] xtic add (myXtic(n2t(i)) n2t(i))
set xrange[GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX]
replot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (merged graphs with varying time data ranging from 30 h to 360 h, without changing the rest of the script)

[image]

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

gnuplot4.4.0 did not have `sum` which would require some workaround.
The random test data generation is probably also not possible or difficult in 4.4.0 and 4.6.0.
Furthermore, I couldn't find bold face in gnuplot 4.6.0. Actually, @maij, cool attempt for bold face in gnuplot4.6, however, at some point you will get a bold or double grid line as well.
So, instead I shifted the dates down by one line. Maybe there are better ways to "highlight" the date.

```
### replace midnight xtic time by date 
reset

FILE        = "SO39997342.dat"
SecPerHour  = 3600
SecPerDay   = 24*SecPerHour
myTimeFmtIn = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"
              
set xdata time
myTimeFmtOut = "%H:%M"
set format x myTimeFmtOut."\n"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"
set key noautotitle
set grid x
set grid y

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1)):2 w l

isMidnight(t)      = int(t)/SecPerDay == t/SecPerDay
myXtic(t)          = isMidnight(t) ? strftime("\n%b %d",t) : strftime(myTimeFmtOut,t)
n2t(i)             = d0*SecPerDay + i*SecPerDay*d2
maxLabelCount      = 8
numberOfDays       = (d0=ceil(GPVAL_X_MIN/SecPerDay),d1=floor(GPVAL_X_MAX/SecPerDay),d1-d0)
getNLabels(c,cmax) = (c0=0, c<=cmax ? (c0=c,d2=1) : (sum [j=2:cmax] (c/j<=cmax && !c0 ? (c0=c/j,d2=j) : 0)), c0)
NLabels            = getNLabels(numberOfDays,maxLabelCount)

set for [i=0:NLabels] xtic add (myXtic(n2t(i)) n2t(i))
set xrange[GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX]
replot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]